# I don't understand the shell sort complexity with shell gap 8,4,2,1

Tags: c++, complexity-theory, shellsort

If I use the gap from shell with always lowering gap=n/2 how can I simply get the math behind the complexity. I know and read all other questions here but it doesn't seem obvious to me.

What I got until now:

For shell (every gap before 1, so before insertion sort starts) we have is

```
 n/2, n/4, n/8,..., 1
```

and for insertion sort we have

```
n^2
```

This together means:

```
n^2+(n^2)/2 + (n^2)/4 + ,..., + 2n^2
```

So this together means I have a worst-case of O(n^2)?

Is that correct so far?

How can I prove that?

Comment: Shell sort complexity is a very tough nut to crack.  I believe the overall complexity is a fractional power between 1 and 2 (so 3/2 or thereabouts, but not as simple as 3/2).  The pattern of the gaps can affect that complexity, IIRC.

Comment: Thank you. But can anybody here tell me if I am on the right way. The duplicate link does not help my for MY problem.